# Kill the child process when the child process output satisfies the condition？

Tags: python, subprocess

I want Python to kill this process if the output of the child process meets the criteria

For example this is a infinity loop `while_file.py`, it print 0 to 999 then looks like there's no response.

```
i = 0
while 1:
    if i < 1000:
        print i
    i += 1
```

I want to check if the output of the child process is 999, then kill it.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmd):
    pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    while True:
        r = pro.stdout.read()
        print r
        if r == 999:
            os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print run_cmd('python while_file.py')
```

But it seems no response... why? Is it be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- "read" function (from pro.stoud.read) reads the whole file (until EOF). Which in your case will not work because the stdout is never close, which means no EOF. You should use readline
- when you are reading you are reading strings not numbers (so you should compare with "999" not with 999)
- I would recommend making sure there is no buffering (can get nasty later if something stays in a buffer)

The changed codes:

```
import sys

i = 0
while True:
    if i < 1000:
        print i
        sys.stdout.flush()
    i += 1
```

and

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmd):
    pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    while True:
        r = pro.stdout.readline()
        r = r.strip()
        print(r)
        if r == "999":
            os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
            print("Process killed")
            break

if __name__=='__main__':
    print run_cmd('PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1; python a.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a good idea or not, but here is a way you can do it:

> while_file.py

```
i = 0
while 1:
    if i < 1000:
        print(i)
        i += 1
```

> stackoverflow.py

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmd):
    pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    for line in iter(pro.stdout.readline, ''):
        r = line.rstrip()
        print(r)
        if r == b'999':
            os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
            print("True !")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(run_cmd('python while_file.py'))
```